# Python 3 - How to replace a str with a str at a certain index in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to loop through a csv file and remove '-' from the items in the first column. I also do some other cleanup changes as well (unimportant for this q). I am getting a syntax error when trying to use the `str.replace()` function.

```
with open('fron.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        del row[10:]
        del row[8]
        del row[5:7]
        del row[2:4]
        row[0] = row[0].replace('-',''))
        row.append('Fron')
        newlist.append(row)
print(newlist)
```

Incorrect syntax for the following code line

```
row[0] = row[0].replace('-',''))
```

I can do the following and it works:

```
row[0] = '1'
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Extra `parentheses` --> `row[0].replace('-',''))`

Answer (score 1):

`row[0] = row[0].replace('-',''))`

This line has extra close parenthesis `)` at the end.

Comment: Have you ever been in public and asked a really stupid question and wanted to disappear afterwards? ........

Answer (score 0):

It should be `row[0] = row[0].replace('-','')` , not `row[0] = row[0].replace('-',''))`.

> Remove extra closing parenthesis `)`

Answer (score 0):

***this will work:***

row[0] = row[0].replace('-','')